# Unknown number of targets from one prerequisite?

Tags: makefile

I have a process which takes an input file (call it test.in) and produces some number of output files (name of the pattern test-[0-9]?.out).  The process should always produce at least 1 output file (test-1.out), but the number of output files will depend on the contents of the input file (with the number growing sequentially on each subsequent output file).  Is there a way to capture this dependency in a make rule or do I need to content myself with just listing that guaranteed first target (using it to determine out-of-date status) and writing the deletion of all files of this form into the recipe explicitly?

Comment: That solution sounds good.

Comment: Another way is producing an archive of the output files (tar or zip), but it could complicate usage since you most likely need to extract the files before use.

Comment: Hmm...  Perhaps not an archive, but a regular folder. Can folders be targets of a makefile rule?

Comment: Yes, but up-to-date checks get weird because of how folders work on the filesystem. You'd have to declare the folder as PHONY and settle with it always being remade. Btw, make sure to tag the person you respond to, e.g. "@Andreas Hmm... Perhaps not an archive...". Otherwise I get no notification of your attempt for discussion.

Comment: @Andreas, sorry about not tagging.  I thought commenters were automatically notified of additional comments.  Further, what do you mean by "up-to-date checks get weird because of how folders work on the filesystem"?  Weird in what way?

Comment: "Since the timestamp on a directory is typically updated when any of the files inside the directory are updated this Makefile does too much work.": https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/making-directories-gnu-make

Comment: @Andreas Ah, okay so the directory idea would only reasonably work if I didn't use it for anything else (not just in the makefile, but elsewhere on the system too).  That would be difficult to keep track of as I need to be able to use the output files.  Most of the time that's just reading them, but you never know when they might get `touch`ed or otherwise modified accidentally.

Comment: Something came to mind: "order only prerequisites". These are prerequisites that are only built if missing. Good for directories. Example: `dirA/fileA.out: | dirA`. Link: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html

Answer (score 1):

Posting my proposed solution from the question (which based on @Beta's comment and its up votes seems to be reasonable):

Only name the guaranteed first target and have the recipe for that target delete the other files in the pattern:

```
test-1.out : test.in
        -rm test-[0-9].out test-[0-9][0-9].out
        <rest of recipe to produce all test-*.out files from test.in>
```

In this case the status of test-1.out is used as a stand-in for the status of all the output files.  If it is out of date, they all are.  The first line of the recipe guarantees the removal of all the output files (up to test-99.out, if more are produced than additional globbing patterns will be needed) so that once the recipe is finished, only the new ones exist (especially important if the update reduces the number of output files).